# Show Administrate Attribute in One Area But Not In Another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administrate

I'm creating a Learning Management System. I've got Users enrolled in Courses. I'd like to show when a User has completed a course on the Users Show page. Like this:

[image]

If I add the `complete` Attribute in `app/dashboards/course_dashboard.rb` under `COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES`, it shows in the Course Index page also, which I don't want:

[image]

How can I add this `complete` attribute to the user's course information on the User Show page (as in the first image) but not add it to the Course Index page (as in the second image)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Administrate doesn't support this out of the box. However it's possible with a little bit of Ruby trickery. This is unofficial and the exact implementation may change with new versions of Administrate. It should work with **Administrate 0.15**, and probably other versions.

The key is this template in Administrate's code: https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/blob/c16b8d1ee3a5ef1d622f9470738e89d73dbb8f1b/app/views/administrate/application/_collection.html.erb

There are two lines that are important here. The first one lists the table headers `<th>`, and it is this one:

```
<% collection_presenter.attribute_types.each do |attr_name, attr_type| %>
```

The second one lists the data columns `<td>` for each record, and it looks like this:

```
<% collection_presenter.attributes_for(resource).each do |attribute| %>
```

The link is to the template that Administrate uses to render collections. This can be an index page, or a list of records in a HasMany field. In each of the lines above, it iterates through the collection attributes defined for the dashboard, as returned by `collection_presenter.attribute_types` and `collection_presenter.attributes_for(...)`, depending on the case.

In order to achieve your desired effect, you need those lists to be different when rendering an index page or when rendering the HasMany list. Currently there isn't an option for HasMany fields to dictate that this list has to be any different in their case.

Fortunately we can hack something together here.

First, remove `:complete` from `CourseDashboard::COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES`. You don't want it listed in the index page, so it shouldn't appear there. **Do not** remove it from `CourseDashboard::ATTRIBUTE_TYPES`, as we still need to define it so that we can use it elsewhere.

Second, create a new field. I'm going to call it `CustomHasMany`, but it could be anything:

```
$ ./bin/rails g administrate:field custom_has_many
      create  app/fields/custom_has_many_field.rb
      create  app/views/fields/custom_has_many_field/_show.html.erb
      create  app/views/fields/custom_has_many_field/_index.html.erb
      create  app/views/fields/custom_has_many_field/_form.html.erb
```

We'll use this field for your `courses` attribute in `UserDashboard`:

```rb
require "administrate/base_dashboard"

class UserDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard
  ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    # ...
    courses: CustomHasManyField
    # ...
  }
```

This is not going to work initially, as the field is new. The first thing it needs is to copy the behaviour of the existing `HasMany` field. We can do this with class inheritance:

```rb
class CustomHasManyField < Administrate::Field::HasMany
end
```

This won't quite mimic the `HasMany` field because it's using the basic templates provided by the generator. Let's tell it to use the `has_many` templates instead:

```rb
class CustomHasManyField < Administrate::Field::HasMany
  def to_partial_path
    "/fields/has_many/#{page}"
  end
end
```

OK, so now it should be the same as a `HasMany` field. So far this has been using public interfaces and "official" Administrate stuff. I have to admit that `to_partial_path` is not well documented, but I think it's stable enough.

So now we have to tell it to add `complete` to the list of fields... This is where the hack comes in play.

If you read the source code of Administrate, you'll find that `collection_presenter` above is provided by the upper-level template. In turn this is defined as `field.associated_collection(order)`, where `field` is the field object, which in our case is an instance of `CustomHasManyField`.

So if we can hack `CustomHasManyField#associated_collection` to return a collection whose `attribute_types` and `attributes_for` include `:complete`... we should be ok?

Looking at the code for collections, we can see that both lists are in turn based on the result of another method `attribute_names`, which is the source of truth as to which attributes should be rendered: https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/blob/c16b8d1ee3a5ef1d622f9470738e89d73dbb8f1b/lib/administrate/page/collection.rb If we modify this `attribute_names` method, the rest should follow suit.

Monkeypatching to the rescue:

```rb
class CustomHasManyField < Administrate::Field::HasMany
  def associated_collection(*)
    collection = super

    def collection.attribute_names
      [:complete] + super
    end

    collection
  end

  def to_partial_path
    "/fields/has_many/#{page}"
  end
end
```

That looks like it works in my computer. Does it work for you?

As for doing this in a more official manner... Do you feel like creating a PR for the project?

Comment: I'm getting "uninitialized constant Administrate::Field::LimitedHasManyField" on `courses: Field::LimitedHasManyField`. Perhaps I've added the `LimitedHasManyField` class in the wrong place? I added it in app/fields/limited_has_many_field.rb.

Comment: Ah, I found it. Someone else had [the same problem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/159#issuecomment-155200795) a few years back. It should be `courses: LimitedHasManyField`. The thing is, this doesn't solve the problem. I've still got a *complete* entry on the Courses Index page.

Comment: Apologies, I only monkeypatched enough to fix the table headers `<th>`, but not the table records `<td>`. I have modified the code to be generic enough to work for both.

Comment: With these changes I'm getting "can't modify frozen Array: [:complete, :title, :lessons, :users]" in the `collection.attribute_names` method.

Comment: The `fields.dup.delete(:complete)` change fixes the error, but I'm still getting the *complete* entry on the Courses Index page.

Comment: Oh, darn. I did it the other way around. I hid it in `HasMany`, but you want it hidden in the index page. In that case, delist it from `CourseDashboard::COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES`, and change `attribute_names` to do `[:complete] + super`. Let me know if it works, and I'll fix the answer properly.

Comment: Yep, that's got it. Thank you so much. I really appreciate you sticking with me on this.

Comment: No worries. Fixed now. Thank you for the prompt feedback.

Comment: old answer but, was helpful to me today (associations to show fewer columns in the parent's show than their own index). Appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

Check out the documentation in https://administrate-demo.herokuapp.com/customizing_dashboards

You need to add the attribute in SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES. Not in COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES.

Comment: Perhaps I explained my issue poorly, but this is not what I'm trying to accomplish. If I add `complete` to `SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES` it will show on the Course show page. I don't want it there. I want `complete` to show *only* on the course information of the User show page. I've updated my question.

Comment: As I understand you need to declare `complete` in ` ATTRIBUTE_TYPES` of your `course_dashboard.rb` not in `COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES`. Then in your `user_dashboard.rb` declare the user association in ` ATTRIBUTE_TYPES`  and  call it in  `SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES`

 `COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES` are the attributes that appear in the index template.

Comment: I have made the `complete` *declaration* in the `ATTRIBUTE_TYPES` array. I don't understand what you mean by "declare the user association in user_dashbaord.rb." Can you elaborate on that?